# Write content from a byte[] to Alfresco repo

Tags: java, alfresco

In java using itext I created a merged PDf that is in a byte[]. How can I write it to the Alfresco repository? I know about this code to write content into repository, but it doesnt accept byte[]

In the example code, mergedDocument is a byte[].

```
destinationNode = createDestinationNode(fileName, 
                            (NodeRef)params.get(PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER), targetNodeRef, inplace);

writer = cs.getWriter(destinationNode, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);

writer.setEncoding(targetReader.getEncoding()); // original
                                                               // encoding
writer.setMimetype(FILE_MIMETYPE);

// Put it in the repo
writer.putContent(mergedDocument);
```

thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `putContent` method of `ContentWriter` has theses options :

```
writer.putContent(ContentReader);
writer.putContent(File);
writer.putContent(InputStream);
writer.putContent(String);
```

what about

```
writer.putContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(mergedDocument));
```